# How to dynamically create 2d array with for loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i have 2d array in this form:

```
GrupaArtikala [] grupaArtikala = parser.getObjektiArtikli();

 Object[][] data = {
                       {grupaArtikala[1].getId(), grupaArtikala[1].getSifra(), grupaArtikala[1].getNaziv(), grupaArtikala[1].getIkonaID()},
                       {grupaArtikala[2].getId(), grupaArtikala[2].getSifra(), grupaArtikala[2].getNaziv(), grupaArtikala[2].getIkonaID()},
                       {grupaArtikala[3].getId(), grupaArtikala[3].getSifra(), grupaArtikala[3].getNaziv(), grupaArtikala[3].getIkonaID()},
                       {grupaArtikala[4].getId(), grupaArtikala[4].getSifra(), grupaArtikala[4].getNaziv(), grupaArtikala[4].getIkonaID()},
                       {grupaArtikala[5].getId(), grupaArtikala[5].getSifra(), grupaArtikala[5].getNaziv(), grupaArtikala[5].getIkonaID(),}
                     };
```

But i wat to create it with nested for loop, Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could incorporate a loop into this:

```
GrupaArtikala[]grupaArtikala=parser.getObjektiArtikli();
        int length = grupaArtikala.length;
        Object[][] data = new Object[length][4];
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            GrupaArtikala temp = grupaAtrikala[i];
            data[i][0] = temp.getId();
            data[i][1] = temp.getSifra();
            //add the rest of your attributes
        }
```